# Etsy API key Location

Tags: api, key, etsy

I don't know if I'm really confused or missing something but I can't find my Etsy API key anywhere.
I have created a new application but all it comes up with is KEYSTRING and Share secret.

I have tried to used the KEYSTRING value in 
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/etsystore?api_key=YOUR_API
but comes up with the wrong user or nothing at all.

Am I looking in the wrong place as Im starting to pull my hair out

Matt

Answer (score 0):

1. Just follow the link: https://www.etsy.com/developers/register
2. Fill fields and create new App.
3. Profit! After that you'll see API key.

Comment: I submitted the form, but I don't even know where to look for the API key.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek it was 2 years ago. Probably something changed. Not working with etsy anymore, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by using just the "Keystring" value that i received while creating the app. The url looks like this -

https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/etsystore?api_key=my_keystring_value

and the response that I got was -

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "user_id": xxxxxx,
      "login_name": "EtsyStore",
      "creation_tsz": 1282269739,
      "user_pub_key": {
        "key": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----xxxx-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
        "key_id": 21832645947
      },
      "referred_by_user_id": null,
      "feedback_info": {
        "count": 3063,
        "score": 100
      }
    }
  ],
  "params": {
    "user_id": "etsystore"
  },
  "type": "User",
  "pagination": {}
}
```

I guess it could be some temporary issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the call you are using does not require an OAuth verification.

If the call does not require the Oauth verification, the KEYSTRING will be acting as the application key and can be passed with the URL for the results.